# How to Fit a long Table in the column width?

Tags: longtable, width, longtabu, resize

[image: This is the output format. I just want to resize this long table to column width.]

```
\begin{longtable}{lcccccc
>{\columncolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}}c |lcccccc|}
\cline{1-7} \cline{9-15}
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{Tests of Normality}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{}} & \multicolumn{7}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{Tests of Normality}}} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} }} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{Kolmogorov-Smirnov}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{Shapiro-Wilk}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} }} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{Kolmogorov-Smirnov}}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{Shapiro-Wilk}}} \\ \cline{2-7} \cline{10-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{Statistic}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{df}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{Sig.}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{Statistic}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{df}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{Sig.}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{}}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{Statistic}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{df}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{Sig.}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{Statistic}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{df}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{Sig.}} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-BT1}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,165} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,947} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,636}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-IS5}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,196} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,907} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,264} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-BT2}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,139} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,929} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,440}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-IS6}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,236} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,120} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,863} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,082} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-BT3}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,188} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,956} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,743}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-IS7}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,258} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,059} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,889} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,166} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-BT4}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,208} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,899} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,212}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-IS8}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,235} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,126} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,834} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,038} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-BT5}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,189} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,939} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,547}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-IS1}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,260} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,053} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,774} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,007} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-BT6}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,196} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,935} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,499}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-IS2}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,146} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,948} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,646} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-BT7}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,137} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,974} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,927}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-IS3}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,317} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,005} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,713} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,001} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-BT8}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,170} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,929} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,440}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-IS4}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,524} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,000} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,366} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,000} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-BT1}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,316} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,006} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,805} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,017}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-IS5}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,299} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,012} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,791} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,011} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-BT2}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,266} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,044} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,888} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,159}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-IS6}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,400} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,751} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,004} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-BT3}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,255} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,064} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,808} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,018}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-IS7}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,482} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,509} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,000} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-BT4}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,195} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,900} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,218}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-IS8}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{333333} } & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{333333} } & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{333333} } & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}{\color[HTML]{333333} } \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-BT5}}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,284} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,021} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,764} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,005}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-LU1}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,200} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,924} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,391} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-BT6}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,258} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,058} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,915} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,315}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-LU2}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,320} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,005} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,660} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,000} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-BT7}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,216} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,866} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,090}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-LU3}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,183} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,946} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,622} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-BT8}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,207} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,923} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,380}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-LU4}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,178} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,942} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,576} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-BT1}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,307} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,008} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,766} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,006}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-LU5}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,145} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,974} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,927} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-BT2}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,256} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,063} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,824} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,028}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-LU6}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,158} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,952} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,692} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-BT3}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,173} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,931} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,456}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-LU7}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,126} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,959} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,778} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-BT4}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,268} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,040} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,861} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,079}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-LU8}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,177} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,927} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,421} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-BT5}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,151} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,937} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,520}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-LU1}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,221} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,183} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,844} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,049} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-BT6}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,174} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,862} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,081}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-LU2}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,305} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,009} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,746} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,003} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-BT7}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,137} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,966} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,848}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-LU3}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,368} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,690} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,001} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-BT8}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,165} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,877} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,120}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-LU4}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,337} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,002} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,816} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,023} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-CG1}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,123} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,972} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,911}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-LU5}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,264} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,047} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,773} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,007} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-CG2}}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,302} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,010} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,763} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,005}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-LU6}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,185} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,904} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,241} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-CG3}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,147} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,917} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,333}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-LU7}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,337} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,002} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,748} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,003} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXCCG4}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,168} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,957} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,754}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-LU8}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,136} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,964} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,827} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-CG5}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,112} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,967} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,866}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-LU1}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,174} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,932} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,465} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-CG6}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,158} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,962} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,807}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-LU2}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,214} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,904} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,242} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-CG7}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,226} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,160} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,933} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,474}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-LU3}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,146} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,958} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,763} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{LXC-CG8}}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,207} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,911} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,288}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-LU4}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,170} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,959} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,775} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-CG1}}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,420} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,638} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,000} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-LU5}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,124} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,937} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,516} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{KVM-CG2}}} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,300} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,011} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,731} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\color[HTML]{333333} 0,002} & {\color[HTML]{333333} } & {\color[HTML]{333333} \textbf{NATIVE-LU6}} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,127} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} ,200*} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,964} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 10} & {\color[HTML]{333333} 0,826} \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: You should post a complete [minimal working example MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) beginning at `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, including all packages and commands necessary to compile your code and create the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘fit in the column width’, exactly?

Comment: This can hardly be a way for presenting information!!

Comment: Fit a table so that all columns fit on the page, in normal table i use the "\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\columnwidth}" but in the longtable it does not work

Comment: Instead of putting these on two consecutive pages, you are putting these as two side-by-side tables. Make 7 columns only and divide the content so that the left half be the first page of the longtable and the right half be the second page of the longtable. You see that gray column? Split at this line.

Comment: Just keep making the font smaller.  You can also play with \tabcolsep.

Answer (score 1):

Your table is to wide to be fit on the page ... but with some effort to change its design, it is possible to obtain:

[image]

(shown are only first eight rows). In it I change the following:

- Instead of `longtable` I suggest you to use `table`.
- Remove columns `df`, since all have the same value (10). This data I move to "Tests of Normality".
- For "Kolmogorov-Smirnov" and "Shapiro-Wilk" use shortens "K-S" and "S-W" respectively.
- Delete all clutter of `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}`.
- Delete all clutter of `\color[HTML]{333333}`.
- Use rules defined in package `booktabs`.
- For table environment use `tabularx`.
- Enlarge text width with use of package `geometry`.

Resulted MWE first eight table data rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X cc cc
                             c
                             X cc cc 
                             }
    \cmidrule[0.5pt]{1-5} \cmidrule[0.5pt]{7-11}
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Tests of Normality}, df$=10$} & 
    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Tests of Normality}, df$=10$}                       \\
    \cmidrule{1-5} \cmidrule{7-11}
%\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{K-S}}
        & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{S-W}}
            &   &   & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{K-S}}
                        & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{S-W}}    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}  \cmidrule(lr){8-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-11}
    & \textbf{Stat.} & \textbf{Sig.}
    & \textbf{Stat.} & \textbf{Sig.}                &   &
    & \textbf{Stat.} & \textbf{Sig.}
    & \textbf{Stat.} & \textbf{Sig.}                                \\
    \cmidrule[0.5pt]{1-5} \cmidrule[0.5pt]{7-11}
\textbf{LXC-BT1}    & 0,165 & 0,200* & 0,947 & 0,636   &   &
\textbf{KVM-IS5}    & 0,196 & 0,200* & 0,907 & 0,264                   \\
%    \addlinespace
\textbf{LXC-BT2}    & 0,139 & 0,200* & 0,929 & 0,440   &   &
\textbf{KVM-IS6}    & 0,236 & 0,120  & 0,863 & 0,082                   \\
    \addlinespace
\textbf{LXC-BT3}    & 0,188 & 0,200* & 0,956 & 0,743   &   &
\textbf{KVM-IS7}    & 0,258 & 0,059  & 0,889 & 0,166                   \\
\textbf{LXC-BT4}    & 0,208 & 0,200* & 0,899 & 0,212   &    &
\textbf{KVM-IS8}    & 0,235 & 0,126  & 0,834 & 0,038                   \\
    \addlinespace
\textbf{LXC-BT5}    & 0,189 & 0,200* & 0,939 & 0,547   &   &
\textbf{NATIVE-IS1} & 0,260 & 0,053  & 0,774 & 0,007                    \\
\textbf{LXC-BT6}    &  0,196 & 0,200* & 0,935 & 0,499  &   &
\textbf{NATIVE-IS2} &  0,146 & 0,200* & 0,948 & 0,646                   \\
    \addlinespace
\textbf{LXC-BT7}    & 0,137 & 0,200* & 0,974 & 0,927   &    &
\cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{\textbf{NATIVE-IS3}}
    & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{0,317}
        & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{0,005}
            & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{0,713}
                & \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}{0,001}                       \\
\textbf{LXC-BT8}    & 0,170 & 0,200* & 0,929 & 0,440    &   &
\textbf{NATIVE-IS4} & 0,524 & 0,000  & 0,366 & 0,000                    \\
    \cmidrule[0.5pt]{1-5} \cmidrule[0.5pt]{7-11}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

If your document has two columns, than instead of `\begin{table} ...\end{table}` you should use `begin{table*}...\end{table*}`.